# What is the strange behavior with SELECT COUNT (distinct CLIEND_ID) From clients_data Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, distinct

Could you please Explain this strange behavior  of count (distinct client_id) statement.

for :

```
SELECT count(distinct client_id) 
from clients_data where bank_name ='SABB' and tstatus = 0
```

I have got 6000 rows

and for

```
SELECT count(distinct client_id)
from clients_data where bank_name ='SABB' and tstatus = 0  and cif_type = 'CARD'
```

I have got 5964
and for

```
SELECT count(distinct client_id) 
from clients_data where bank_name ='SABB' and tstatus = 0  and cif_type = 'LOAN'
```

I have got 42 rows .
but

```
5964 + 42 = 6006
```

and the first query gets only 6000 .
where these extra 6 rows come from ?

Note : Data now is not Available for any suggestions .
the image is [here](http://www.arabteam2000-forum.com/uploads/monthly_10_2011/post-218064-080888900%201319423764.jpg) :

Comment: multiple records for a client_id?

Comment: There are 6 `client_id` that has `cif_type` 'CARD' and `cif_type` 'LOAN'.

Comment: The reason is that client_id is not unique. That's all.

Comment: cif_type either 'CARD' or 'LOAN' , not both because we use '='.

Comment: What does `WITH T AS (SELECT client_id from clients_data where bank_name ='SABB' and tstatus = 0) SELECT * FROM T WHERE cif_type = 'LOAN' INTERSECT SELECT * FROM T WHERE cif_type = 'CARD'` return?

Comment: Also, maybe `cif_type either 'CARD' or 'LOAN'` [constraint is not trusted](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2008/01/12/non-trusted-constraints.aspx). What does `SELECT count(distinct client_id) 
from clients_data where bank_name ='SABB' and tstatus = 0  and cif_type NOT IN ('CARD', 'LOAN')` return ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be six `client_id` that have both a CARD and a LOAN.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT client_id FROM clients_data GROUP by client_id HAVING count(client_id) > 1
```

Do you have multiple records for a specific client_id? Running the above will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest 6 of your client_ids appear in rows with a cif_type of 'LOAN' and also in rows with a cif_type of 'CARD'. Try counting rows in your 3 conditions without the DISTINCT. You should find the numbers then add up.

Answer (score -1):

May be u have some values which have empty or null cif_type .

Comment: That would explain a lower sum of the more specific queries, but they add up to more than the generic one.  (Not my downvote)